# Is Sharp Objects series completely based on the book or is it like GOT?

Tags: book-adaptation, sharp-objects

I haven't read the book or seen the series but interested in them. I see from wiki the book is only 250+ pages. From some careful googling I see that story did not end with the season finale that aired recently which was 8th episode in the first season. I wonder if the series is faithful to the book or is it "based on" the book like GOT?

Comment: Define "faithful". There has never been an adaptation that **exactly** matches the book, as far as I know.

Comment: I would recommend changing the question to target major plot differences between book & show. And also remove any reference to GoT as it would make it primarily opinion based. Welcome New contributor

Answer (score 2):

According to this article from [Elite Daily](https://www.elitedaily.com/p/the-sharp-objects-show-vs-the-book-have-a-few-major-differences-10212124) **there are few big changes compared to the novel**.

> **No television show is perfectly faithful to the book, though some try.
>   Game of Thrones, for example, stayed faithful in their debut season,
>   but it was a 10-hour show adapting 800+ pages. Most novels are not as
>   long, so to fill the 8-to-10 hour brief, extra scenes are added.**
>   That's especially the case in adaptations where the novel is told in
>   the first person point of view and swaps to a third person POV with a
>   camera. **The Sharp Objects show vs. the book is a perfect example of
>   this. With only 254 pages to work from to fill seven hours, there are
>   changes all throughout the series.**

**The following are the changes made**. I have compiled a list based on the article, but the article gives more context to how this changes may affect the work.

1. Camille works and lives in Chicago instead of St. Louis.
2. Camille's response at Natalie's funeral is different.
3. Third person perspective fleshes things out more, including Detective Willis is "nicer" in the novel by spending more time with the character.
4. The Addition of Calhoun Day.
5. Ending change: A girl from school turns up stangled, rather than the accidental discovery of the floor in the dollhouse. Camille also has a breakdown, wanting to cut herself again, but Frank interviens, while Amma happily admits to her crimes and her gang of friends willing to help her do it!